# json_encode can't interpret my xml

Tags: php, json, xml

I want to hand over my XML data to json_encode but nothing happens. My XML file looks like this

```
<check_company_email>
    <text_1>
        <de>eregrthrtjtzj</de>
        <en>*</en>
    </text_1>
</check_company_email>
```

and I want it to hand over to

```
echo json_encode($xml->check_company_email->text_1->$lang);
```

If I do this:

```
$arr="hello";
json_encode($arr);
```

it does work any ideas why?

Comment: If `<check_company_email>` is the XML's root element, then your SimpleXML call is incorrect.

Comment: The XML document starts like this: 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
<check_company_email>
    <text_1>
        <de>eregrthrtjtzj</de>
        <en>*</en>
    </text_1>
</check_company_email>
</root>`

and I call it in another document like this: 
`$xml=simplexml_load_file("include/languages.xml")or die("No language file found");`

It does work if I just put 
`$xml->check_company_email->text_1->$lang`
 in html or echo in php.

Comment: the problem then is that your SimpleXML call returns a SimpleXMLElement object (as every SimpleXML call does) which is encoded differently than a string (esp. since there are no public properties).

Comment: I had that thought too and tried to convert it into a string by different ways but nothing worked. how could I convert it to String?

Comment: You should be able to cast it to string i.e. `echo json_encode((string)$xml->check_company_email->text_1->$lang);`

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: If I use this: 
`echo json_encode($xml->check_company_email->text_1->$lang);` it returns null and if use this:
`echo json_encode((string)$xml->check_company_email->text_1->$lang);` it returns ""

Comment: have you defined `$lang`? and does its value exist in the XML?

Comment: Yes, its either 'de' or 'en'

Comment: The call works fine with the XML from the comment. https://eval.in/999539

Comment: UPDATE:

All of your solutions were right I just had the wrong directory. jokes on me